# What causes this query builder error in my Laravel 8 app?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on a **Laravel 8** app with users, roles and permissions.

I try to get the current user's *list of permissions*.

In `app\Models\Permission.php` I have:

```
class Permission extends Model {
  use HasFactory;

  protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'list'
  ];
}
```

In `app\Models\Role.php` I have:

```
class Role extends Model {
  use HasFactory;

  protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'permission_id'
  ];
}
```

In the controller, I first get the user's *role id*:

```
$user_role = User::where('email', $user->getMail())->first()->role_id;
```

Then, the list of permissions:

```
$user_permissions = Permission::select (
  "roles.name as role_name",
  "permissions.list as permissions_list",
)
->leftJoin("permissions", "roles.permission_id", "=", "permissions.id")
->where('roles.id', $user_role)
->get();
```

The above is intended to be the equivalent of this MySQL query, that works:

```
SELECT roles.name as role_name, permissions.list AS permissions_list
FROM roles LEFT
JOIN permissions ON roles.permission_id = permissions.id WHERE roles.id = 1
```

#### The problem

The Laravel query builder you can see above fails with this message:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'permissions' (SQL: select `roles`.`name`, `permissions`.`list` from `permissions` left join `permissions` on `roles`.`permission_id` = `permissions`.`id` where `roles`.`id` = 1)
```

I can't understand why, since I have tested the MySQL query in phpMyAdmin and *it* works.

##### Where is my mistake?

Comment: `from 'permissions' left join 'permissions` stands out. Try `->leftJoin("roles"`...

Comment: Your manual query is `SELECT ... FROM roles`, but your generated query is `SELECT ... FROM permissions`. Did you maybe mean to start your query with `Role::select()` instead of `Permission::select()`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`->leftJoin("permissions", "roles.permission_id", "=",` 
`"permissions.id")`

should be
`->leftJoin("roles", "roles.permission_id", "=", "permissions.id")`